# Oracle sql loader clob column

Tags: oracle, sql-loader

i'm trying to upload this csv file to oracle table,however i'm getting an error

this is the controlfile i have,

SQL LOADER Control file

```
load data
infile '/tmp/daily_hot_backup.csv'
append
into table BACKUP_POSTGRESQL_LOGS
fields terminated by ","
TRAILING NULLCOLS
(
SERVER_NAME CHAR(120),
DATABASE_NAME CHAR(52),
TIMESTAMP date "DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS" ":timestamp",
INFO CLOB,
BACKUP_ERROR CHAR(1)
);
```

csv file data:
server_name,database_name,timestamp,info,backup_error

```
218vp,fat2p,13-JUL-2022,"pg_basebackup: initiating base backup, waiting for checkpoint to complete
pg_basebackup: checkpoint completed
pg_basebackup: write-ahead log start point: A1/B11330D0 on timeline 15
pg_basebackup: starting background WAL receiver
pg_basebackup: created temporary replication slot ""pg_basebackup_21801""
       0/47524537 kB (0%), 0/1 tablespace (...p/5432/2022-07-13_23_30/base.tar)
   31081/47524537 kB (0%), 0/1 tablespace (...p/5432/2022-07-13_23_30/base.tar)
   95078/47524537 kB (0%), 0/1 tablespace (...p/5432/2022-07-13_23_30/base.tar)
  134387/47524537 kB (0%), 0/1 tablespace (...p/5432/2022-07-13_23_30/base.tar)
  173536/47524537 kB (0%), 0/1 tablespace (...p/5432/2022-07-13_23_30/base.tar)
  211556/47524537 kB (0%), 0/1 tablespace (...p/5432/2022-07-13_23_30/base.tar)
  469901/47524537 kB (0%), 0/1 tablespace (...p/5432/2022-07-13_23_30/base.tar)
  917087/47524537 kB (1%), 0/1 tablespace (...p/5432/2022-07-13_23_30/base.tar)
 1515551/47524537 kB (3%), 0/1 tablespace (...p/5432/2022-07-13_23_30/base.tar)
 1515583/47524537 kB (3%), 0/1 tablespace (...p/5432/2022-07-13_23_30/base.tar)
 1779949/47524537 kB (3%), 0/1 tablespace (...p/5432/2022-07-13_23_30/base.tar)
 2358118/47524537 kB (4%), 0/1 tablespace (...p/5432/2022-07-13_23_30/base.tar)
 2773951/47524537 kB (5%), 0/1 tablespace (...p/5432/2022-07-13_23_30/base.tar)
 3430047/47524537 kB (7%), 0/1 tablespace (...p/5432/2022-07-13_23_30/base.tar)
 3732207/47524537 kB (7%), 0/1 tablespace (...p/5432/2022-07-13_23_30/base.tar)
 4036482/47524537 kB (8%), 0/1 tablespace (...p/5432/2022-07-13_23_30/base.tar)
 4036514/47524537 kB (8%), 0/1 tablespace (...p/5432/2022-07-13_23_30/base.tar)
 4162498/47524537 kB (8%), 0/1 tablespace (...p/5432/2022-07-13_23_30/base.tar)
 4857828/47524537 kB (10%), 0/1 tablespace (...p/5432/2022-07-13_23_30/base.tar)
 5397454/47524537 kB (11%), 0/1 tablespace (...p/5432/2022-07-13_23_30/base.tar)
 5397486/47524537 kB (11%), 0/1 tablespace (...p/5432/2022-07-13_23_30/base.tar)
 5439534/47524537 kB (11%), 0/1 tablespace (...p/5432/2022-07-13_23_30/base.tar)
 5956398/47524537 kB (12%), 0/1 tablespace (...p/5432/2022-07-13_23_30/base.tar)
 6366151/47524537 kB (13%), 0/1 tablespace (...p/5432/2022-07-13_23_30/base.tar)
 6797159/47524537 kB (14%), 0/1 tablespace (...p/5432/2022-07-13_23_30/base.tar)
 6797191/47524537 kB (14%), 0/1 tablespace (...p/5432/2022-07-13_23_30/base.tar)
 7246535/47524537 kB (15%), 0/1 tablespace (...p/5432/2022-07-13_23_30/base.tar)
 7721465/47524537 kB (16%), 0/1 tablespace (...p/5432/2022-07-13_23_30/base.tar)
 7994489/47524537 kB (16%), 0/1 tablespace (...p/5432/2022-07-13_23_30/base.tar)
 8254521/47524537 kB (17%), 0/1 tablespace (...p/5432/2022-07-13_23_30/base.tar)
 8254553/47524537 kB (17%), 0/1 tablespace (...p/5432/2022-07-13_23_30/base.tar)
 8420962/47524537 kB (17%), 0/1 tablespace (...p/5432/2022-07-13_23_30/base.tar)
 8875365/47524537 kB (18%), 0/1 tablespace (...p/5432/2022-07-13_23_30/base.tar)
 9424709/47524537 kB (19%), 0/1 tablespace (...p/5432/2022-07-13_23_30/base.tar)
 9719621/47524537 kB (20%), 0/1 tablespace (...p/5432/2022-07-13_23_30/base.tar)
 9719653/47524537 kB (20%), 0/1 tablespace (...p/5432/2022-07-13_23_30/base.tar)
10102318/47524537 kB (21%), 0/1 tablespace (...p/5432/2022-07-13_23_30/base.tar)
10661742/47524537 kB (22%), 0/1 tablespace (...p/5432/2022-07-13_23_30/base.tar)
11169615/47524537 kB (23%), 0/1 tablespace (...p/5432/2022-07-13_23_30/base.tar)
11169647/47524537 kB (23%), 0/1 tablespace (...p/5432/2022-07-13_23_30/base.tar)
11353935/47524537 kB (23%), 0/1 tablespace (...p/5432/2022-07-13_23_30/base.tar)
11865935/47524537 kB (24%), 0/1 tablespace (...p/5432/2022-07-13_23_30/base.tar)
12248920/47524537 kB (25%), 0/1 tablespace (...p/5432/2022-07-13_23_30/base.tar)
12504920/47524537 kB (26%), 0/1 tablespace (...p/5432/2022-07-13_23_30/base.tar)
12946232/47524537 kB (27%), 0/1 tablespace (...p/5432/2022-07-13_23_30/base.tar)
13159122/47524537 kB (27%), 0/1 tablespace (...p/5432/2022-07-13_23_30/base.tar)
13489011/47524537 kB (28%), 0/1 tablespace (...p/5432/2022-07-13_23_30/base.tar)
13747699/47524537 kB (28%), 0/1 tablespace (...p/5432/2022-07-13_23_30/base.tar)
14018355/47524537 kB (29%), 0/1 tablespace (...p/5432/2022-07-13_23_30/base.tar)
14327283/47524537 kB (30%), 0/1 tablespace (...p/5432/2022-07-13_23_30/base.tar)
14601580/47524537 kB (30%), 0/1 tablespace (...p/5432/2022-07-13_23_30/base.tar)
14601612/47524537 kB (30%), 0/1 tablespace (...p/5432/2022-07-13_23_30/base.tar)
14829644/47524537 kB (31%), 0/1 tablespace (...p/5432/2022-07-13_23_30/base.tar)
15426668/47524537 kB (32%), 0/1 tablespace (...p/5432/2022-07-13_23_30/base.tar)
15886959/47524537 kB (33%), 0/1 tablespace (...p/5432/2022-07-13_23_30/base.tar)
16127183/47524537 kB (33%), 0/1 tablespace (...p/5432/2022-07-13_23_30/base.tar)
16127215/47524537 kB (33%), 0/1 tablespace (...p/5432/2022-07-13_23_30/base.tar)
16164911/47524537 kB (34%), 0/1 tablespace (...p/5432/2022-07-13_23_30/base.tar)
16635481/47524537 kB (35%), 0/1 tablespace (...p/5432/2022-07-13_23_30/base.tar)
17174980/47524537 kB (36%), 0/1 tablespace (...p/5432/2022-07-13_23_30/base.tar)
17474534/47524537 kB (36%), 0/1 tablespace (...p/5432/2022-07-13_23_30/base.tar)
17710182/47524537 kB (37%), 0/1 tablespace (...p/5432/2022-07-13_23_30/base.tar)
17710214/47524537 kB (37%), 0/1 tablespace (...p/5432/2022-07-13_23_30/base.tar)
17904710/47524537 kB (37%), 0/1 tablespace (...p/5432/2022-07-13_23_30/base.tar)
18210662/47524537 kB (38%), 0/1 tablespace (...p/5432/2022-07-13_23_30/base.tar)
18635752/47524537 kB (39%), 0/1 tablespace (...p/5432/2022-07-13_23_30/base.tar)
19021736/47524537 kB (40%), 0/1 tablespace (...p/5432/2022-07-13_23_30/base.tar)
19307880/47524537 kB (40%), 0/1 tablespace (...p/5432/2022-07-13_23_30/base.tar)
19307912/47524537 kB (40%), 0/1 tablespace (...p/5432/2022-07-13_23_30/base.tar)
19485929/47524537 kB (41%), 0/1 tablespace (...p/5432/2022-07-13_23_30/base.tar)
19761777/47524537 kB (41%), 0/1 tablespace (...p/5432/2022-07-13_23_30/base.tar)
20278619/47524537 kB (42%), 0/1 tablespace (...p/5432/2022-07-13_23_30/base.tar)
20699854/47524537 kB (43%), 0/1 tablespace (...p/5432/2022-07-13_23_30/base.tar)
20985864/47524537 kB (44%), 0/1 tablespace (...p/5432/2022-07-13_23_30/base.tar)
21252065/47524537 kB (44%), 0/1 tablespace (...p/5432/2022-07-13_23_30/base.tar)
21515306/47524537 kB (45%), 0/1 tablespace (...p/5432/2022-07-13_23_30/base.tar)
21515338/47524537 kB (45%), 0/1 tablespace (...p/5432/2022-07-13_23_30/base.tar)
21904239/47524537 kB (46%), 0/1 tablespace (...p/5432/2022-07-13_23_30/base.tar)
22230392/47524537 kB (46%), 0/1 tablespace (...p/5432/2022-07-13_23_30/base.tar)
22772248/47524537 kB (47%), 0/1 tablespace (...p/5432/2022-07-13_23_30/base.tar)
23253331/47524537 kB (48%), 0/1 tablespace (...p/5432/2022-07-13_23_30/base.tar)
23365171/47524537 kB (49%), 0/1 tablespace (...p/5432/2022-07-13_23_30/base.tar)
23822362/47524537 kB (50%), 0/1 tablespace (...p/5432/2022-07-13_23_30/base.tar)
24215970/47524537 kB (50%), 0/1 tablespace (...p/5432/2022-07-13_23_30/base.tar)
24472674/47524537 kB (51%), 0/1 tablespace (...p/5432/2022-07-13_23_30/base.tar)
24706210/47524537 kB (51%), 0/1 tablespace (...p/5432/2022-07-13_23_30/base.tar)
24939746/47524537 kB (52%), 0/1 tablespace (...p/5432/2022-07-13_23_30/base.tar)
24939778/47524537 kB (52%), 0/1 tablespace (...p/5432/2022-07-13_23_30/base.tar)
24971714/47524537 kB (52%), 0/1 tablespace (...p/5432/2022-07-13_23_30/base.tar)
25574018/47524537 kB (53%), 0/1 tablespace (...p/5432/2022-07-13_23_30/base.tar)
26145475/47524537 kB (55%), 0/1 tablespace (...p/5432/2022-07-13_23_30/base.tar)
26440036/47524537 kB (55%), 0/1 tablespace (...p/5432/2022-07-13_23_30/base.tar)
26440068/47524537 kB (55%), 0/1 tablespace (...p/5432/2022-07-13_23_30/base.tar)
26549829/47524537 kB (55%), 0/1 tablespace (...p/5432/2022-07-13_23_30/base.tar)
27015301/47524537 kB (56%), 0/1 tablespace (...p/5432/2022-07-13_23_30/base.tar)
27329469/47524537 kB (57%), 0/1 tablespace (...p/5432/2022-07-13_23_30/base.tar)
27775471/47524537 kB (58%), 0/1 tablespace (...p/5432/2022-07-13_23_30/base.tar)
28170767/47524537 kB (59%), 0/1 tablespace (...p/5432/2022-07-13_23_30/base.tar)
28170799/47524537 kB (59%), 0/1 tablespace (...p/5432/2022-07-13_23_30/base.tar)
28607727/47524537 kB (60%), 0/1 tablespace (...p/5432/2022-07-13_23_30/base.tar)
29070865/47524537 kB (61%), 0/1 tablespace (...p/5432/2022-07-13_23_30/base.tar)
29353612/47524537 kB (61%), 0/1 tablespace (...p/5432/2022-07-13_23_30/base.tar)
29603174/47524537 kB (62%), 0/1 tablespace (...p/5432/2022-07-13_23_30/base.tar)
29603206/47524537 kB (62%), 0/1 tablespace (...p/5432/2022-07-13_23_30/base.tar)
29971142/47524537 kB (63%), 0/1 tablespace (...p/5432/2022-07-13_23_30/base.tar)
30544583/47524537 kB (64%), 0/1 tablespace (...p/5432/2022-07-13_23_30/base.tar)
31019335/47524537 kB (65%), 0/1 tablespace (...p/5432/2022-07-13_23_30/base.tar)
31019367/47524537 kB (65%), 0/1 tablespace (...p/5432/2022-07-13_23_30/base.tar)
31135767/47524537 kB (65%), 0/1 tablespace (...p/5432/2022-07-13_23_30/base.tar)
31540601/47524537 kB (66%), 0/1 tablespace (...p/5432/2022-07-13_23_30/base.tar)
32019213/47524537 kB (67%), 0/1 tablespace (...p/5432/2022-07-13_23_30/base.tar)
32470189/47524537 kB (68%), 0/1 tablespace (...p/5432/2022-07-13_23_30/base.tar)
32470221/47524537 kB (68%), 0/1 tablespace (...p/5432/2022-07-13_23_30/base.tar)
32654542/47524537 kB (68%), 0/1 tablespace (...p/5432/2022-07-13_23_30/base.tar)
33147534/47524537 kB (69%), 0/1 tablespace (...p/5432/2022-07-13_23_30/base.tar)
33650040/47524537 kB (70%), 0/1 tablespace (...p/5432/2022-07-13_23_30/base.tar)
34052376/47524537 kB (71%), 0/1 tablespace (...p/5432/2022-07-13_23_30/base.tar)
34052408/47524537 kB (71%), 0/1 tablespace (...p/5432/2022-07-13_23_30/base.tar)
34234385/47524537 kB (72%), 0/1 tablespace (...p/5432/2022-07-13_23_30/base.tar)
34804049/47524537 kB (73%), 0/1 tablespace (...p/5432/2022-07-13_23_30/base.tar)
35146131/47524537 kB (73%), 0/1 tablespace (...p/5432/2022-07-13_23_30/base.tar)
35401584/47524537 kB (74%), 0/1 tablespace (...p/5432/2022-07-13_23_30/base.tar)
35636766/47524537 kB (74%), 0/1 tablespace (...p/5432/2022-07-13_23_30/base.tar)
35636798/47524537 kB (74%), 0/1 tablespace (...p/5432/2022-07-13_23_30/base.tar)
35780778/47524537 kB (75%), 0/1 tablespace (...p/5432/2022-07-13_23_30/base.tar)
36147274/47524537 kB (76%), 0/1 tablespace (...p/5432/2022-07-13_23_30/base.tar)
36519704/47524537 kB (76%), 0/1 tablespace (...p/5432/2022-07-13_23_30/base.tar)
36988359/47524537 kB (77%), 0/1 tablespace (...p/5432/2022-07-13_23_30/base.tar)
37352967/47524537 kB (78%), 0/1 tablespace (...p/5432/2022-07-13_23_30/base.tar)
37843336/47524537 kB (79%), 0/1 tablespace (...p/5432/2022-07-13_23_30/base.tar)
38336008/47524537 kB (80%), 0/1 tablespace (...p/5432/2022-07-13_23_30/base.tar)
38698916/47524537 kB (81%), 0/1 tablespace (...p/5432/2022-07-13_23_30/base.tar)
38853252/47524537 kB (81%), 0/1 tablespace (...p/5432/2022-07-13_23_30/base.tar)
39153830/47524537 kB (82%), 0/1 tablespace (...p/5432/2022-07-13_23_30/base.tar)
39568800/47524537 kB (83%), 0/1 tablespace (...p/5432/2022-07-13_23_30/base.tar)
39568800/47524537 kB (83%), 0/1 tablespace (...p/5432/2022-07-13_23_30/base.tar)
40047126/47524537 kB (84%), 0/1 tablespace (...p/5432/2022-07-13_23_30/base.tar)
40136510/47524537 kB (84%), 0/1 tablespace (...p/5432/2022-07-13_23_30/base.tar)
40574718/47524537 kB (85%), 0/1 tablespace (...p/5432/2022-07-13_23_30/base.tar)
41109241/47524537 kB (86%), 0/1 tablespace (...p/5432/2022-07-13_23_30/base.tar)
41109273/47524537 kB (86%), 0/1 tablespace (...p/5432/2022-07-13_23_30/base.tar)
41149721/47524537 kB (86%), 0/1 tablespace (...p/5432/2022-07-13_23_30/base.tar)
41735929/47524537 kB (87%), 0/1 tablespace (...p/5432/2022-07-13_23_30/base.tar)
42071802/47524537 kB (88%), 0/1 tablespace (...p/5432/2022-07-13_23_30/base.tar)
42381562/47524537 kB (89%), 0/1 tablespace (...p/5432/2022-07-13_23_30/base.tar)
42735354/47524537 kB (89%), 0/1 tablespace (...p/5432/2022-07-13_23_30/base.tar)
42986266/47524537 kB (90%), 0/1 tablespace (...p/5432/2022-07-13_23_30/base.tar)
43240395/47524537 kB (90%), 0/1 tablespace (...p/5432/2022-07-13_23_30/base.tar)
43444295/47524537 kB (91%), 0/1 tablespace (...p/5432/2022-07-13_23_30/base.tar)
43798785/47524537 kB (92%), 0/1 tablespace (...p/5432/2022-07-13_23_30/base.tar)
43912721/47524537 kB (92%), 0/1 tablespace (...p/5432/2022-07-13_23_30/base.tar)
44150579/47524537 kB (92%), 0/1 tablespace (...p/5432/2022-07-13_23_30/base.tar)
44150611/47524537 kB (92%), 0/1 tablespace (...p/5432/2022-07-13_23_30/base.tar)
44189138/47524537 kB (92%), 0/1 tablespace (...p/5432/2022-07-13_23_30/base.tar)
44489881/47524537 kB (93%), 0/1 tablespace (...p/5432/2022-07-13_23_30/base.tar)
44948089/47524537 kB (94%), 0/1 tablespace (...p/5432/2022-07-13_23_30/base.tar)
45312643/47524537 kB (95%), 0/1 tablespace (...p/5432/2022-07-13_23_30/base.tar)
45624355/47524537 kB (96%), 0/1 tablespace (...p/5432/2022-07-13_23_30/base.tar)
45624387/47524537 kB (96%), 0/1 tablespace (...p/5432/2022-07-13_23_30/base.tar)
45955363/47524537 kB (96%), 0/1 tablespace (...p/5432/2022-07-13_23_30/base.tar)
46469427/47524537 kB (97%), 0/1 tablespace (...p/5432/2022-07-13_23_30/base.tar)
46953308/47524537 kB (98%), 0/1 tablespace (...p/5432/2022-07-13_23_30/base.tar)
47300046/47524537 kB (99%), 0/1 tablespace (...p/5432/2022-07-13_23_30/base.tar)
47300078/47524537 kB (99%), 0/1 tablespace (...p/5432/2022-07-13_23_30/base.tar)
47326382/47524537 kB (99%), 0/1 tablespace (...p/5432/2022-07-13_23_30/base.tar)
47395451/47524537 kB (99%), 0/1 tablespace (...p/5432/2022-07-13_23_30/base.tar)
47433594/47524537 kB (99%), 0/1 tablespace (...p/5432/2022-07-13_23_30/base.tar)
47524467/47524537 kB (99%), 0/1 tablespace (...p/5432/2022-07-13_23_30/base.tar)
47524467/47524537 kB (100%), 1/1 tablespace
pg_basebackup: write-ahead log end point: A1/B3A59720
pg_basebackup: waiting for background process to finish streaming ...
pg_basebackup: syncing data to disk ...
pg_basebackup: base backup completed",N`
```

The data i'm looking to upload has 5 column , the column info is the CLOB which is failing with error.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the streaming record format. Your adjusted loader configuration will be:

```
load data
infile '/tmp/daily_hot_backup.csv'  "str '|\n'"
append
into table BACKUP_POSTGRESQL_LOGS
fields terminated by "," optionally enclosed by '"'
```

Comment: Getting this error, Record 1: Rejected - Error on table BACKUP_POSTGRESQL_LOGS, column BACKUP_ERROR.
Field in data file exceeds maximum length

Comment: Your text is probably too long, you may need to load it in chunks since it's over 4k symbols.